# Getting EnvironmentError when trying to install packages with pip3

Tags: python, python-3.x, macos, pip

This is a newly built laptop with MacOS Catalina and python3.7.

For some reason, when I try to install new packages with "pip3", I get a notification the package is already installed AND I get an error.

Here is one example:

```
 ~ pip3 install pylint
Requirement already satisfied: pylint in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages (2.3.1)
No metadata found in ./Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages
Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/Users/tennis.smith/Library/Python/3.7/lib/python/site-packages/pylint-2.3.1.dist-info/METADATA'
```

Anyone have any idea what's broken or misconfigured?

Thanks